# Custom script in footer of every page

Tags: joomla

Im writing a Joomla extension that allows a custom script to run on every "site" page.
I've already done the backend part including database access, but, now I'm completely stuck as to how to add custom javascript to every page of the "site", no matter what theme is installed. Also, I do NOT want to disturb any other stuff on the page.

I have been searching the net for almost 4hours, plus have tried modifying index.php file of templates in various ways, but all in-vain.

Any help?

Thanx in advance...

**EDIT**
I need to distribute this as an extension...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a [content plugin](http://docs.joomla.org/Category%3aPlugin_Development). For example

```
class plgContentMyplugin extends JPlugin
{
    public function onContentPrepare($context, &$article, &$params, $page = 0)
    {
        $document = JFactory::getDocument();
        $document->addScript(JURI::base().'plugins/content/myplugin/js/myscript.js' );
    }
}
```

This will add `myscript.js` in the `<head>`. Just check in docs how to package the plugin

Comment: oh sorry to inform back....yes, I did manage :). Although I was unable to find exact callback that is invoked JUST before body end tag to add content, i neverthless managed to preg_match body end tag and add custom script in 'onAfterRender()' function. Its working fine. Thnk u sooo much :)....u helped me two times :)

Comment: Now i have two zips: one for managing backend(in the form of extension), and the other for frontend(in the form of plugin). Can I distribute them as one zip, I mean managed by one single manufest file? Or I'll have to upload them separately?

Comment: @NitinBansal you can manage them as one zip, check http://docs.joomla.org/Package